# Mounting drive as unpriviliged user with systemd mount unit or systemd-mount

Tags: systemd, mount, automounting, udisks

Is there any way to mount an external drive as an unpriviliged user, either with a pre-defined `mount` unit or with a transiently generated one with `systemd-mount`?

If I write a file `run-media-myuser-somelabel.mount` in `~/.config/systemd/user` and try to mount, I get the following error:

```
$ systemctl --user start 'run-media-myuser-somelabel.mount'
Job failed. See "journalctl -xe" for details.

$ journalctl -e
<snip>
Jul 30 22:20:47 mybox systemd[615]: run-media-user-somelabel.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 30 22:20:47 mybox mount[892871]: mount: /run/media/user/somelabel: must be superuser to use mount.
Jul 30 22:20:47 mybox mount[892871]:        dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
Jul 30 22:20:47 mybox systemd[615]: Failed to mount somelabel disk.
```

I guess this is not surprising, I cannot run `mount` as an unpriviliged user. The same thing happens with `systemd-mount --user /dev/disk/by-label/somelabel`. Actually in both cases I have to create the mountpoint `/run/media/user/somelabel`—which required root permissions anyway—to even get to this error.

However, I can of course mount the same disk with `udisksctl` to `/run/media/user/somelabel` as an unpriviliged user. Can I do the same with the `systemd` mount facilities (not a regular service that calls `udisksctl`) without granting extra priviliges to `user`?